# azure mobile services for authentication in MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure

I would like to use the Azure Mobile Services authentication from an Azure MVC site at a different URL http://mysite.azurewebsites.com. So I want to access https://mysite.azure-mobile.net/login/google to do authentication by Google, and based on good authentication use the token or something like that. After authentication the page goes to https://mysite.azure-mobile.net/login/done with the token. Is this possible at all, and how do I identify that I'm logged in, and who that logged in user is.

Comment: Why do you want to use Mobile Services authentication in particular?

Comment: I would like to do this because Mobile Services returns userID = GoogeAccout:12345 but if you do normal OpenID to google account you get userID = 2df93g92dfwdc, in other words, they don't match. So its impossible to let a user get their data from a non-azuremobile app.